# Solving a particular nonlinear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

I am trying to solve the recurrence relation $a_{n}=\alpha a_{n-1}^2+\beta a_{n-1}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. I have been trying to find specific techniques for solving this equation in closed form. I have not come across any such work, yet. I may not be looking into the proper literature as I guess this problem to be a well studied one. Any pointer towards the solution and/or the direct solution will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recurrence equation is called a [Quadratic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html),most quadratic maps don't have a closed form solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get an approximation. If $\alpha a_n^2$ dominates, a first cut is $a_{n + 1} = \alpha a_n^2$,
which you can solve by taking logarithms and solving the resulting equation. If $a_n \to 0$, the second term eventually dominates and a first cut is $a_{n + 1} = \beta a_n$, also easy to solve.